# How to find default sound driver in linux?

Tags: c, linux, audio

I am trying this example: http://hzqtc.github.io/2012/05/play-mp3-with-libmpg123-and-libao.html to play an mp3 file on Debian. I was bale to build and make a binary with required shared libraries. However, when I try to execute the binary with following command nothing happens.

```
$./play SoundFiles/abc.mp3
```

After some debugging, I found following function call in the example is returning -1

```
driver = ao_default_driver_id();
```

which according to `libao` documentation is a failure. How do I find out default sound driver? I am able to play sound with mpg123 package. But for my task, I need to use the library compiled from source. Am I missing something here?